# Always show success message although input wrong code

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I got some problem when I want to delete code in table product.
But whatever I input in textbox, it always show success message.

Here is my delete.php

```
<?php

session_start();
include_once "config.php";

$code = ($_POST['product_code']);

$sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE product_code='".$code."'";

if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Product Deleted");</script>';
    header("Location:http://localhost/olshop/remove_product.php");
} else {
    echo '<script>alert("No such Product Exists");</script>';
    header("Location:http://localhost/olshop/remove_product.php");
}
```

And here the config.php

```
<?php

$currency = '&#82;&#112; '; //Currency Character or code

$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = 'online';
$db_host = 'localhost';

$shipping_cost = 1.50; //shipping cost
$taxes = array( //List your Taxes percent here.
    'VAT' => 12,
    'Service Tax' => 5
);
//connect to MySql
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: `if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql))` will be true if the syntax is SQL correct. You should move it outside of `if` and implement an existence check instead as suggested in the answers.

Answer (score -1):

The `mysqli_query` will always return `true` as long as your sql statement is correct without syntax error. It's nothing to do with if the code is existing or not.

So you should do a validation to check if the code is existing right before the deleting.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_code='".$code."'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Product Deleted");';
    echo 'document.location.href="http://localhost/olshop/remove_product.php";';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Comment: getting error " mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: @Brad can u help me

Comment: @Brad this question is not about security but whether or not the logic works.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the question was about... people blindly copy/paste code from Stack Overflow all the time.  If your code has such a blindingly obvious and dangerous security flaw in it, it's going to get a downvote from me and a comment so that you and others know why.

Answer (score -1):

```
Simple Session Massage-->

  if(isset($_POST["id"]))
  {
    foreach($_POST["id"] as $id)
  {
     echo $query = "DELETE FROM `user` WHERE id = '".$id."'";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die;
   }
     $msg3="You have Successfully deleted record";
     $_SESSION['msgdelete']=$msg3; 
     echo "<script>window.location.href='super_distributor.php';</script>";
   }
```

show success message to enter this code-->

```
  if(isset($_SESSION['msgdelete']))
    { 
      echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>".$_SESSION['msgdelete']."</div>"; 
      unset($_SESSION['msgdelete']); 
     }
```